# Python: convert a column vector to .xyz file format

Tags: python-2.7

I have a column vector of a molecular geometry in the format

```
x1
y1
z1
x2
y2
z2
x3
y3
z3
x4
y4
z4
x5
y5
z5
x6
y6
z6
x7
y7
z7
x8
y8
z8
```

I would like to convert this into a .xyz file format:

```
number of atoms
comment line
C x1 y1 z1
H x2 y2 z2
H x3 y3 z3
C x4 y4 z4
H x5 y5 z5
H x6 y6 z6
O x7 y7 z7
O x8 y8 z8
```

Is this easily done? If it's difficult to add the atom types, then just rearranging the coordinates to the columns would be good (at least it reduces the amount of manual labour).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the letters O, H, C mean nor how to add this information (I am not a chemist). Where they are stored ? But if you are a scientist, you probably use the numpy module. So here is a simple solution to transpose your rows three by three:

```
import numpy as np
import csv 

#assuming your vector is in a text file
vector = np.genfromtxt('yourfilename.txt',dtype='str')

a = np.array(vector)
a = a.reshape((-1, 3))

print(a)
```

Output :

```
[['x1' 'y1' 'z1']
 ['x2' 'y2' 'z2']
 ['x3' 'y3' 'z3']
 ['x4' 'y4' 'z4']
 ['x5' 'y5' 'z5']
 ['x6' 'y6' 'z6']
 ['x7' 'y7' 'z7']
 ['x8' 'y8' 'z8']]

"""
The output is a list of lists in which each element is a row. 
Numpy has a simple method to write a 2D array in a csv file :
np.savetxt("youfilename.csv", a, delimiter=",")
but since I get a bug in this moment, I will use a classical method.
"""
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(a)
```

Your csv file :

```
x1,y1,z1

x2,y2,z2

x3,y3,z3

x4,y4,z4

x5,y5,z5

x6,y6,z6

x7,y7,z7

x8,y8,z8
```

Comment: Well I also need to import a text file that contains the numbers (ordered as a column vector). What does the "\n" mean?

Comment: @Yoda \n means "newline", which is a character like any other. They can be erased. I will edit and clarify my answer.